# underVolt shows but DC meter +5

Tags: power-supply

volt and current measurement dongle from power supply shows 5.00 volts within 4% and current is less than  500 ma but lightning bolt showa undervoltage. WHY?

Comment: Need more information. Where is the measurement device - at the power supply or at the Pi? How long is the power cable? Which Pi? And what do you have attached to the pi?

Comment: Also the dongle may be broken (possibly by design). What voltage does it display anyway? Average, MIN, MAX, RMS?

Answer (score 1):

Because the voltage is dropping beneath 4.65V.  Presumably there are periods when something kicks in and requires more current.  You need a higher amperage power supply.

Comment: Higher amperage rating supply.

Comment: @Seamus incorporated comment.

Comment: @Seamus I think you both mean higher **current** - what the OP needs is a supply that delivers the correct **voltage** @ the required current.

Answer (score 0):

Either the voltage is too low **AND/OR** the resistance of the cable is too high - causing voltage to drop on current peaks.

The Pi is sensitive to very short transients (which are stretched to ~3 sec for display. See [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations)